# Historical relation between computer science and the theory of dynamical systems

Tags: soft-question, computer-science, math-history, dynamical-systems

I wonder if there is any historical relation between the fields of Dynamical systems (and related fields such as Optimal control) and (theoretical) Computer science. The reason for which I ask this question is, that several older major journals, now considered to be primarily focused on theoretical computer science, were originally devoted both to computer science and to dynamical systems.

The example of such journals can be for instance *Journal of Computer and System Sciences*. Mainly in its beginnings (however, I am too young to remember these times), it published papers both on computer science and on system sciences, and both of the fields seemed to be of equal importance. Moreover, also the name of the journal *Information and Control* suggests the relation to optimal control. However, this journal was always focused mainly on theoretical computer science and information theory.

So therefore I wonder, if these fields (nowadays, up to my knowledge, considered to be substantially different) have something in common or if there is some purpose to consider these fields to be related.

Comment: Belongs to http://cs.stackexchange.com ?